# в зависимости от нажатой кнопки менять информацию на 2м View Controller

Tags: xcode, swift

в MenuViewController есть две кнопки - " месяц" и "неделя", сейчас в CalendarViewController содержится информация только о месяце. Как в зависимости от нажатой кнопки менять информацию на CalendarViewController? 
Я пробовал:
в MenuViewController:

```
  @IBAction func buttonClick(sender: AnyObject) {

            let calendarVC = kConstantObj.SetIntialMainViewController("CalendarViewController")
            self.window?.rootViewController = calendarVC
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }

        if sender  == mounthButton {
               calendarVC.presentationMode(.MonthView)

        } else {
```

calendarVC.presentationMode(.WeekView)
    }
    }
в CalendarViewController :

```
 func presentationMode() -> CalendarMode {
            return CalendarMode.MonthView
        }
```

но Xcode выдает ошибку 'use of unresolved identifier 'calendarVC' 
То есть два основных вопроса - как поменять функцию в CalendarViewController , и как по нажатию на неделю/месяц переходить на CalendarViewController на нужную информацию?

Answer (score 0):

Можно это релизовать через делегирование или через NSNotificationCenter

Вот тут ответ на ваш вопрос:

1. [NSNotificationCenter](http://swiftbook.ru/content/koposhilka/nsnotification-center-class)
2. [Делегирование](http://swiftbook.ru/content/koposhilka/delegation-swift)